# What Azure AD is my Azure DevOps organization associated with?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

When [setting up a new Organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=azdevops) it states:

> If you're using an Azure AD account, confirm the directory that you're
>   connected to. If you belong to multiple directories, ensure that you
>   want to connect this directory to your organization. Changing the
>   directory now is easier than changing the directory later.

An associated image notes the AD it is connected to, but the UI has changed since them. I just created a new organization with an ID that is part of multiple ADs (via B2B), but I see no way to determine (or alter) the directory I am connected to, whatever that may be.

Ultimately, I want to create two organizations tied to the same Azure AD instance - doable?